# How capitalize the to first letter of a lot of data?

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python, barely 20-25 days old, I have researched a lot and though I have found a way to capitalize (first letter), the name and address data by using the following python code , I used 'atom editor' to write the code, and  'Powershell' to check it.

Raw data:

```
john deere
apt. no. 23,
9th floor, sixth avenue,
michael street, new arc,
edmonton, canada.
```

Code

```
value = """john deere apt.
         no. 23, 9th floor,
         sixth avenue, michael street,
         new arc,
         edmonton,
         canada.
         """
# Convert to title case.
result = value.title()
print(result)
```

Result:

```
John Deere
Apt. No. 23,
9th Floor, Sixth Avenue,
Michael Street, New Arc,
Edmonton, Canada.
```

Now suppose if I have to capitalize the first letters of such names & addresses which are in 'Note Pad' and twenty at a time, how can I do that and how can I input the data and how can I get it back on 'Notepad' as output. I would be very grateful if anyone can guide me.

This is how the data appears in Notepad

1. ```
   john deere
   apt. no. 23,
   9th floor, sixth avenue,
   michael street, new arc,
   edmonton, canada.
   ```
2. ```
   peter simons.
   ..address here.
   .........
   ..........
   ```
3. ```
   florence nightingale
   ...........
   ...........
   ..........
   ```

so on and so forth....

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overwrite contents of actual file then you can write the output to a new file. However using same file, let's say file name is `data.txt`.

```
with open('data.txt', 'w+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.title()
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
f = open("infile.txt", "r") # change this with your file name, open your source file to read
out = open("outfile.txt", "w") # open your output file to write
for line in f: # read from input line by line
    out.write(line.title()) # write to your output line by line
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module. It makes it very easy to process a file **in-place** and will even optionally create a backup file.

Here's how use it to solve your problem:

```
import fileinput

filename = 'addresses.txt'
backup = '.bak'  # will create backup file named 'addresses.txt.bak'

with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True, backup=backup) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.title(), end='')  # end='' suppresses extra newline normally added

print('done')
```

However, using the string `.title()` method isn't always going to work correctly because it will do things like turn something like `"sak's 5th ave"` into `"Sak'S 5Th Ave"` since it recognizes words as simply any group of consecutive letters.

One workaround for those kind of issues is by using Python's regex (regular expression) module, named [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re), to define your own custom word pattern matching logic.

To illustrate how to do this, here's the previous code modified to use `re` and a custom regex pattern that will avoid the two problem cases previously mentioned:

```
import re

def titlecase(s):
    return re.sub(r"\b[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
                  lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() + mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
                  s)

filename = 'addresses.txt'
backup = '.bak'  # will create backup file named 'addresses.txt.bak'

with fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True, backup=backup) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(titlecase(line), end='')  # end='' suppresses extra newline normally added

print('done')
```